# How do I assimilate the division of wages per hour between permanent employee and intern in Dax?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to do it with `IF`, but it gives a syntax error.

Below is the measurement.

```
sal hour = 
[salary per day]/8
IF(SELECTEDVALUE('RH[office]) = "Internship" / 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [IF](https://dax.guide/if/) function is not correct

The function is

```
IF (<Logical Test>, <Result if true> , <Result if false>)
```

Using my example:

[image]

```
Selected Value Check = [Hours] / IF(SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Column2]) = "A",  6, 8)
```

You need to check IF it is internship is true, then return 6 else return 8

```
sal hour = [salary per day] / IF(SELECTEDVALUE('RH[office]) = "Internship", 6, 8)
```

You should use the [DIVIDE](https://dax.guide/divide/) function as well, as it will handle divide by zero.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I had tried "IF, OR, And", but it gave a syntax error, the division in the middle of the measure I was making a mistake.